# Dynamics CRM pass the value from parent workflow to child worklow

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a workflow that executes a child workflow? (Account - Contact)
Is there a way to pass values from the parent to the child? via plugin or custom workflow activity?

Answer (score 2):

Not using a child workflow. You could consider using a field in CRM, or looking into actions which accept inputs.